Podman - Mongo DB Clustering
I am working to setup Mongo DB cluster (replica set) using podman containers. I have set them up as 1 primary and 2 secondary nodes. The replica set configuration works fine and I can login to primary container and using mongosh and add a document, which successfully gets replicated to both the secondary nodes fine.
My containers are running on a single host (eventually each node will be setup on different hosts). My rs config looks like this:
{
  _id: 'rs1',
  version: 5,
  term: 1,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: 'host.containers.internal:27017',
     },
    {
      _id: 1,
      host: 'host.containers.internal:27018',
     },
    {
      _id: 2,
      host: 'host.containers.internal:27019',
     }
  ]
}

The mongo db ports for each container (27017, 27018, 27019) are mapped out to similar ports on the host, when the podman container is created. But when I am try to connect to the primary node via host DNS using Mongo DB Compass (mongodb://admin:*******@mongo.container.host:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs1&readPreference=primary), I get an error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND host.containers.internal. I am guessing this error is related to how the replica set was configured using host.container.internal.
I am new to podoman networking stuff, any help on how to setup the mongo db containers so that they can "see" each other but also are accessible via the hosts DNS (incase they are setup on different hosts), is much appreciated!
